# C++ Trying to declare a struct's base, then initialize as a derived struct later

Tags: c++

What I have so far:

```
enum type {
  type0,
  type1,
  type2
};

struct Base {
  type t;

  Base () {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
  vector<int> mem;

  Derived () {
    t = type0;
  } 
};

int main()  {
  Base s;
    switch(...) {
    case ... :
      s = Derived()
      for (...) {
        s.mem.push_back(num) // error: 'struct Base' has no member named 'mem'
      }
      break;
    ...
    } 

  // do some more stuff with s

  return 0;
}
```

What's the best way to do what I'm trying to do? I want to start with a generic struct and change it to be more specific once I figure out the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is not wise to assign derived object to base object. Derived object takes more space, and that space is simply not there when space for `Base s` was being determined, so those members are sliced off. You should work with pointers instead.

Second, set the object with derived pointer, then in the end assign that pointer value to base pointer:

```
Base* s;
//...

Derived* d = new Derived();
// Do whatever you like with d
s = d;

// Delete the object eventually
delete s;
```

Also, make the destructor of `Base` virtual. That ensures that `Derived` destructor will also be called when you call `delete s`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need virtual method to access members in derived struct.

Declare `virtual vector<int>& get_mem() = 0;` in `Base` and `override` it in derived.

Also, as @Dialecticus say, you should use pointers or references, because `Base` would be abstract class.

Comment: I think I may have chosen the wrong data structure. The problem is I have several derived structs with different members

Comment: Then you can't generalize there use.

Comment: So is there a data structure that lends itself to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: If these members has something common, that you want to use, you can try templates